# How to read data from multiple table using data reader in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

Following is my codes, I can't execute the data reader, it keeps showing the error of There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.' So can anyone please help to solve the error of my codes?

```
    Dim selectSql As String
    Dim selectSql2 As String

    conn = New SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Assignment.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30")

    selectSql = "Select [Field of Study Deg], [Major Deg], [Institute Or University Deg], [Grade Deg],[Graduation Date Deg], [Field of Study Dip], [Major Dip], [Institute Or University Dip], [Grade Dip], [Graduation Date Dip] From [Education Background] Where [Full Name] = @fullname"

    selectSql2 = "Select [Company Name 1], [Position Title 1], [Position Level 1], [Specialization 1], [Industry 1], [Duration 1], [Work Description 1], [Company Name 2], [Position Title 2], [Position Level 2], [Specialization 2], [Industry 2], [Duration 2], [Work Description 2] From [Employment History] Where [Full Name] = @fullname"

    conn.Open()

    'create the command 
    'the command is used for executing the SQL statement
    cmd = New SqlCommand(selectSql, conn)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fullname", txtFullname.Text)
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader() 'executes the reader to read record

    cmd2 = New SqlCommand(selectSql2, conn)
    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fullname", txtFullname.Text)
    dr2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader()

    If dr.HasRows And dr2.HasRows Then
        btnEdit.Enabled = True
        btnBrowse.Enabled = True

        'read the data from the record 
        dr.Read()
        dr2.Read()

        'display 
        txtField1.Text = dr("Field of Study Deg").ToString
        txtMajor1.Text = dr("Major Deg").ToString
        txtInstitute1.Text = dr("Institute Or University Deg").ToString
        txtGrade1.Text = dr("Grade Deg").ToString
        mskGradDate1.Text = dr("Graduation Date Deg").ToString

        txtCompany1.Text = dr2("Company Name 1").ToString
        txtPosTitle1.Text = dr2("Position Title 1").ToString
        txtPosLevel1.Text = dr2("Position Level 1").ToString
        txtSpecial1.Text = dr2("Specialization 1").ToString
        txtIndustry1.Text = dr2("Industry 1").ToString
        txtDuration1.Text = dr2("Duration 1").ToString
        txtWork1.Text = dr2("Work Description 1").ToString

    Else
        'record not found
        MessageBox.Show("Full name cannot be found. Please check the name again.", "Unable to Search", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
    End If
    conn.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: Suggestion, why not use `INNER JOIN` in sql string and You'll get joined values from both table into one `SqlDataReader`. for example : `SELECT * FROM [Education Background] INNER JOIN [Employment History] ON [Education Background].[Full Name]=[Employment History].[Full Name] WHERE [Full Name]=@fullname;` Then You don't need to deal with each reader separated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Multiple Data Readers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2057534/using-multiple-data-readers).  It is not quite the same as your question, but the question itself shows one way and it was seeking alternatives for an older system.

Comment: Sorry I am still quite new to vb.net so for inner join, just the select statement will be different then other codes remain the same? or can you please help me amend my codes, thanks a lot!

Comment: `inner join` is `sql query` and doesn't have anything with `vb.net`. By provided suggestion in prev.comment you don't need anymore `cmd2` and `dr2`, everything is in `dr`

Comment: Maybe this will help [inner join reference](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most database objects need to be closed and disposed (their `.Dispose` method called) `Using...End Using` blocks take care of this for you even it there is an error.

For Sql Server use the `.Add` method for parameters. See http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/
and
https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/
and another one:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/195937/addwithvalue-performance-and-plan-cache-implications
Here is another
https://andrevdm.blogspot.com/2010/12/parameterised-queriesdont-use.html

Notice that the first reader is closed and disposed by an `End Using` before the second reader is created. The connection stays open for both commands.

I really don't like updating the user interface while the connection is open but we will leave that for another time.

```
Private Sub OPCode()
    Dim selectSql = "Select [Field of Study Deg], [Major Deg], [Institute Or University Deg], [Grade Deg],[Graduation Date Deg], [Field of Study Dip], [Major Dip], [Institute Or University Dip], [Grade Dip], [Graduation Date Dip] From [Education Background] Where [Full Name] = @fullname"
    Dim selectSql2 = "Select [Company Name 1], [Position Title 1], [Position Level 1], [Specialization 1], [Industry 1], [Duration 1], [Work Description 1], [Company Name 2], [Position Title 2], [Position Level 2], [Specialization 2], [Industry 2], [Duration 2], [Work Description 2] From [Employment History] Where [Full Name] = @fullname"

    Using conn = New SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Assignment.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30")
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand(selectSql, conn)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@fullname", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200).Value = txtFullname.Text
            conn.Open()
            Using dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
                dr.Read()
                txtField1.Text = dr("Field of Study Deg").ToString
                txtMajor1.Text = dr("Major Deg").ToString
                txtInstitute1.Text = dr("Institute Or University Deg").ToString
                txtGrade1.Text = dr("Grade Deg").ToString
                mskGradDate1.Text = dr("Graduation Date Deg").ToString
            End Using
        End Using
        Using cmd2 As New SqlCommand(selectSql2, conn)
            cmd2.Parameters.Add("@fullname", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200).Value = txtFullname.Text
            Using dr2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader
                dr2.Read()
                txtCompany1.Text = dr2("Company Name 1").ToString
                txtPosTitle1.Text = dr2("Position Title 1").ToString
                txtPosLevel1.Text = dr2("Position Level 1").ToString
                txtSpecial1.Text = dr2("Specialization 1").ToString
                txtIndustry1.Text = dr2("Industry 1").ToString
                txtDuration1.Text = dr2("Duration 1").ToString
                txtWork1.Text = dr2("Work Description 1").ToString
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: Then if I will like to read from data from combobox, how can the data be retrieve as I tried with this codes but it failed.

cboProficiency.Text = dr("Proficiency").ToString

Comment: I did not see cboProficiency in your original code.

Comment: yes, I do not put the that in my original code but now I would like to retrieve data at the combobox.

Comment: Is this an existing combo box that already contains the items?

Comment: yes the combobox contains items but I would like to read the data and show inside there and update it as well.

Comment: As long as the value can be found in the combo box, that should work but I don't see where you are downloading a field called Proficiency.

Comment: These are my codes : 

selectSql3 = "Select [Skill 1], [Years 1], [Proficiency 1] From [Skills] Where [Full Name] = @fullname" 

 Using cmd3 = New SqlCommand(selectSql3, conn)
           cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fullname", txtFullname.Text)
           Using dr3 = cmd3.ExecuteReader
                        dr3.Read()
                        txtSkill1.Text = dr3("Skill 1").ToString
                        txtYears1.Text = dr3("Years 1").ToString
                        cboProficiency1.Text = dr3("Proficiency 1").ToString

Comment: In neither of your select statements are there any fields called Proficiency. You reader can't read a field that isn't there.

Comment: OK. We could have saved a lot of chatter, if you told me that at the beginning. Can you check the value of `dr3("Proficiency 1").ToString` and confirm that it is contained in the combo box?

Comment: yes, I saved the data in my codes here : 

With cmd4.Parameters
                    .AddWithValue("@Fullname", txtFullname.Text)
                    .AddWithValue("@Skill1", txtSkill1.Text)
                    .AddWithValue("@Years1", txtYears1.Text)
                    .AddWithValue("@Proficiency1", cboProficiency1.Text)

Comment: No more .AddWithValue. I gave you several links explaining why.

Comment: Alright but how should I read my data in combo box?

Comment: This has moved so far from your original question that I think you should ask a new question with all this additional code. It is very hard to read code in comment format.